# Do we have $\limsup\{X_n\leq x\}\subset\{\limsup X_n \leq x\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's assume that the lim sup and lim inf are well defined, and $X_n$ are convergent r.v. to $X$.

Do we have $\limsup\{X_n\leq x\}\subset\{\limsup X_n \leq x\}$?

Here's my try:
$$\limsup\{X_n\leq x\}=\{ X_n \leq x \text{ i.o.}\}=\{\forall_N \exists_{n>N} X_n\leq x\}=\{\forall_{\epsilon>0}\forall_N \exists_{n>N} X_n\leq x+\epsilon\}=\{\liminf X_n\leq x\}= \{\limsup X_n \leq x\}$$

and what about $\liminf\{X_n\leq x\}=\{\liminf X_n \leq x\}$?

I ask this, because in Resnick's Probability Path, in page 258, there's a proof, where he states something, for the purpose of this question, equivalent to :

> For all $h>0$, we have $$\{X\leq x-h\}\subset \liminf \{X_n\leq
> x\}\subset\limsup\{X_n\leq x\}\subset \{X\leq x\}$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X_n=(-1)^n$. Then $\limsup\{X_n\le 0\}\supset\{\limsup{X}_n\le 0\}$. We can show, however, that $\limsup\{X_n\le x\}\subseteq \{\liminf X_n\le x\}$. Let $Y_n:=\inf_{m\ge n}X_m$. Then
$$
\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge n}\{X_m\le  x\}\subseteq\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\{Y_n\le x\}=\left\{\sup_{n\ge 1}\{Y_n\}\le x\right\}=\left\{\liminf_{n\to\infty}X_n\le x\right\}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one doubt. Couldn't we also have always an equality, when we put the inf inside the set, instead of ⊆(last line) ?

Comment: "we put the inf inside the set"? We don't put it inside the set. We compare two sets... You can easily come up with an example in which equality fails.